# In ActiveRecord, fetch items by a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three Classes I don't get to edit, and one I do.

```
class MailingAddress < ActiveRecord::Base #yes, this is singular
    belongs_to :person
end
```

And

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mail_addresses #Yes, it's written as plural
end
```

And

```
class Clubs < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :persons #yes, listed as plural
end
```

Each one doesn't have any defs designed for fetching the others.

And here's my def in the file I can edit.

```
def find_addresses (club)
  club.persons.map do |person|
    user = ActiveRecord::Base::Person::find(person)
    p user.inspect #shows the current Person
    user_addresses = ActiveRecord::Base::MailAddress::select(user) # <-- This line doesn't work
  end
end
```

I've also tried replacing the problematic line with

```
user_addresses = ActiveRecord::joins(:mail_address).where(person: user)
```

But that doesn't work either (apparently ActiveRecord joins isn't a thing). 
How should I write that line so I can get an array or hash with all the mail addresses for the user?

Comment: See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables for examples of specifying conditions on the joined tables.

Comment: [You should not use double colons to invoke methods.](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#double-colons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the methods provided by Rails:

```
def find_addresses(club)
  club.persons.map do |person|
    user = Person.find(person)
    user_addresses = user.mail_addresses
  end
end
```

Note that you can use `Person`, there is no need to prefix the class name.

If you want to make it more efficient (less SQL queries), you can do:

```
def find_addresses(club)
  MailAddress.joins(person: :clubs).where(clubs: { id: club.id })
end
```

Comment: `where(club: { id: club.id })` should be `where(clubs: { id: club.id })` since table names are used inside `where` statements.

Comment: (best-practices) Don't use `::` for class methods, just use `Person.find(person)`

Comment: @3limin4t0r thx, fixed :)
@colinross thx, no idea why I used `::`

Comment: Probably because you copied it from the question that way.

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't excuse me ;)

Comment: I'm still a Ruby-newbie (A Rewbie?) so I have an excuse. XD